# Program works when separated into 2 programs but not when used in the same program

Tags: c, menu, while-loop, switch-statement

I have a project and it is consisting of a Menu and Sub-programs using `switch-case`.

My problem is Menu number 3 which is not working properly in my program, but when I separate it in another program, it is working.

This is the link of my CPP http://www.mediafire.com/download/4tj6slw1edrdu2h/My+program.rar

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
void gotoxy(short x, short y) {COORD pos = {x, y};
SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), pos);
}
int main ()
{
    //BORDER and Effects Design :)  
    int bx=0, by=0, choice,intctr=1; double doublegrade=0, doublesum=0;
    int reader1,letter;int counterf,reader=0;
    int seconds,second1,hour,minute;//(Seconds)
    float x=-5;float y=-45.23;char name[25];char iname[30];
    //intctr,doublegrademdoublesum=(average)
    //int reader1,letter,iname(Falling Asterisk)
    //x,y,char,MATH
    bx=20;by=7;
    while(bx<=50 && by<=31)
    {
    gotoxy(bx,by);
    system("COLOR 2");
    printf("%c", 3);
    bx++;
    if(bx==50)
    {bx=20; by++;}
    }
    //Loob Ng Menu (lalagyan ng Spaces!!) 21-49
    bx=21; by=8;
    while(bx<=48 && by<=30)
    {
    gotoxy(bx,by);
    printf(" ");
    system("COLOR 4");
    bx++;
    if(bx==49)
    {bx=21;by++;}
    }
   //Print ng MENU
    while(choice!=5)
{ 
    bx=33; by=10;
    gotoxy(bx, by);
    printf("MENU");bx=26;by=12;
    gotoxy(bx,by);
    printf("(1) AVERAGE");by++;
    gotoxy(bx,by);
    printf("(2) MATH");by++;
    gotoxy(bx,by);
    printf("(3) FALLING ASTERISK");by++;
    gotoxy(bx,by);
    printf("(4) SECONDS");by++;
    gotoxy(bx,by);
    printf("(5) EXIT");bx=32; by++;
    gotoxy(bx,by);
    printf("CHOICE: ");bx=39;
    gotoxy(bx,by);
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    system ("CLS");
    switch (choice)
    { 
//case1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
       case 1:bx=20; by=7;
               while(bx<=50 && by<=31)
                 {
                    gotoxy(bx,by);
                    system("COLOR 5");
                    printf("%c", 5);
                    bx++;
                    if(bx==50)
                    {bx=20; by++;}
                 }
              bx=21; by=8;
               while(bx<=48 && by<=30)
                 {
                    gotoxy(bx,by);
                    printf(" ");
                    bx++;
                    if(bx==49)
                    {bx=21;by++;}
                    }
                    bx=26; by=14;
                    while(intctr<6)
                    {
                    gotoxy(bx,by);
                    printf("Enter grade %d: ", intctr);
                    gotoxy(41,by);
                    scanf("%lf", &doublegrade);
                    doublesum= doublesum + doublegrade;
                    intctr++;by++;
                    }
            gotoxy(bx,by);
            printf("Average:%.2lf", doublesum/5);
            getch();
            bx=21; by=8;
            while(bx<=48 && by<=30)
            {
             gotoxy(bx,by);
             printf(" ");
             system("COLOR E");
             bx++;
             if(bx==49)
             {bx=21;by++;}
            }
            getch(); break;
//case2XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
       case 2:     bx=20; by=7;
                     while(bx<=50 && by<=31)
                        {
                         gotoxy(bx,by);
                         system("COLOR 6");
                         printf("%c", 2);
                         bx++;
                         if(bx==50)
                         {bx=20; by++;}
                        }
                   bx=21; by=8;
                    while(bx<=48 && by<=30)
                        {
                            gotoxy(bx,by);
                            printf(" ");
                            bx++;
                            if(bx==49)
                            {bx=21;by++;}
                            }
                    bx=25;by=16;
                    gotoxy(bx,by);
                    printf("Mathematical Funtions\n");by++;
                    gotoxy(bx,by);
                    printf("abs= %d\n", abs(x));by++;
                    gotoxy(bx,by);
                    printf("fabs= %.2f\n", fabs(y)); by++;
                    gotoxy(bx,by);
                    printf("ceil= %.2f\n", ceil(y)); by++;
                    gotoxy(bx,by);
                    printf("floor= %.2f\n", floor (y));by++;
                    gotoxy(bx,by);
                    printf("ceil= %.2f\n", ceil(45.23));by++;
                    gotoxy(bx,by);
                    printf("floor= %.2f\n", floor(45.23));by++;
                    y=pow(2,3);
                    gotoxy(bx,by);
                    printf("pow= %.2f\n",y);by++;
                    gotoxy(bx,by);
                    printf("sqrt= %.2f\n", sqrt(4));
                    bx=21; by=8;
                    while(bx<=48 && by<=30)
                     {
                        gotoxy(bx,by);
                        printf(" ");
                        system("COLOR B");
                        bx++;
                        if(bx==49)
                        {bx=21;by++;}
                     }
                    getch ();break;
//Case3XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        case 3:             system ("CLS");
                            bx=20; by=7;      
                            while(bx<=50 && by<=31)
                            {
                                gotoxy(bx,by);
                                system("COLOR 8");
                                printf("%c", 1);
                                bx++;
                                if(bx==50)
                                {bx=20; by++;}
                            }bx=21; by=8;
                            while(bx<=48 && by<=30)
                            {
                                gotoxy(bx,by);
                                printf(" ");
                                bx++;
                                if(bx==49)
                                {bx=21;by++;}
                            }   bx=27;by=12;
                    gotoxy(bx,by);
                    printf("FALLING ASTERISK");
                    by=14;bx=23;gotoxy(bx,by);
                    printf("Input name: ");bx=34;by=14;
                    fgets(iname,30,stdin);bx=32;by=16;
                    gotoxy(bx,by);
                    printf("%s", iname);
                    counterf=strlen(iname);
                    bx=32;by=16;
                            while(reader<counterf)
                            {
                                gotoxy(bx,by);
                                printf("*");
                                Sleep (500);
                                gotoxy(bx,by);
                                Sleep (500);
                                printf(" ");
                                by++;reader1++;
                                if(reader1==counterf)
                                {reader++;gotoxy(bx,by);printf("%c",iname[letter]);
                                letter++;by=16;bx++;reader1=0;}
                            }
                            bx=21; by=8;
                            while(bx<=48 && by<=30)
                            {
                             gotoxy(bx,by);
                             printf(" ");
                             system("COLOR D");
                             bx++;
                             if(bx==49)
                             {bx=21;by++;}
                            }
                            getch();break;
//CASE4XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        case 4:             system ("CLS");
                            bx=20;by=7;
                            while(bx<=50 && by<=31)
                            {
                                gotoxy(bx,by);
                                system("COLOR A");
                                printf("%c", 219);
                                bx++;
                                if(bx==50)
                                {bx=20; by++;}
                            }
                                bx=21; by=8;
                            while(bx<=48 && by<=30)
                            {
                                gotoxy(bx,by);
                                printf(" ");
                                system("COLOR 4");
                                bx++;
                                if(bx==49)
                                {bx=21;by++;}
                            }
                            bx=27;by=16;
                            gotoxy(bx,by);
                            printf("ENTER SECONDS: ");
                            scanf("%d",&seconds);
                            hour=seconds/3600;
                            minute=(seconds%3600)/60;
                            second1=seconds%60;bx=23,by=18;
                            gotoxy(bx,by);
                            printf("Hour:%d Minute:%d Seconds:%d", hour,minute,second1);
                            getch();
                            bx=21; by=8;
                            while(bx<=48 && by<=30)
                            {
                                 gotoxy(bx,by);
                                 printf(" ");
                                 system("COLOR B");
                                 bx++;
                                 if(bx==49)
                                {bx=21;by++;}
                            }
                            getch();break;        
        case 5:printf("BYEBYE");
                getch();
               return 0;
        default:
        gotoxy(27,19);printf("Invalid Number!");  
    }//switch
}//MAIN WHILE
getch();
return 0;
    }
```

When I separate CASE 3.(I did not change anything)

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
void gotoxy(short x, short y) {
COORD pos = {x, y};
SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), pos);
}
int main ()                  
{   int bx=20, by=7, choice,intctr=1;
    int reader1,letter;
    char iname[200];
                            system ("CLS");      
                            while(bx<=50 && by<=31)
                            {
                                gotoxy(bx,by);
                                system("COLOR 8");
                                printf("%c", 1);
                                bx++;
                                if(bx==50)
                                {bx=20; by++;}
                            }bx=21; by=8;
                            while(bx<=48 && by<=30)
                            {
                                gotoxy(bx,by);
                                printf(" ");
                                bx++;
                                if(bx==49)
                                {bx=21;by++;}
                            }   bx=27;by=12;
                    gotoxy(bx,by);
                    printf("FALLING ASTERISK");
                    int counterf,reader=1;
                    by=14;bx=23;gotoxy(bx,by);
                    printf("Input name: ");bx=34;by=14;
                    fgets(iname,200,stdin);bx=32;by=16;
                    gotoxy(bx,by);
                    printf("%s", iname);
                    counterf=strlen(iname);
                    bx=32;by=16;
                            while(reader<counterf)
                            {
                                gotoxy(bx,by);
                                printf("*");
                                Sleep (500);
                                gotoxy(bx,by);
                                Sleep (500);
                                printf(" ");
                                by++;reader1++;
                                if(reader1==counterf)
                                {reader++;gotoxy(bx,by);printf("%c",iname[letter]);
                                letter++;by=16;bx++;reader1=0;}
                            }

getch ();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is too long :(( but ok i will do it

Comment: [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32666457/edit) to include the code.

Comment: Guys Thank you for Helping

Comment: Too long, unindented and unreadable code. Post indented and readable code and that too, a [mcve].

Comment: The problem is in Case 3. I separated it(2nd code) and it worked, but in the first code if you use case 3 it is not reading arrays of characters

Comment: Blind guess: Try adding `int c;` at the start of your program and then try `while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);` before the `fgets` which does not work.

Comment: WTF? can you explain it to me? pls pls pls pls pls SENPAI

Comment: @Mark Did that work?

Comment: @ Mark Glad to hear that. @user3121023 has given the explanation. I've also posted an answer giving the details.

Comment: Looking at this kind of code, I just *have* to give some advice about coding in general. 1.) Learn about [formatting styles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Styles), chose one and follow it consistently. I personally prefer *Allman style*, but this is a matter of taste -- being consistent is important! 2.) Look up the term *magic number*. Don't use them all over your code, if you need them, give them meaningful names in a central place, e.g. by using `#define`.

Comment: 3.) Long functions are error-prone and illegible and make it hard to refactor later. Learn about separation of concerns and distribute your code to functions doing *one* logical, self-contained job. If there are to many functions, distribute them to different source files, so functions logically related to each other are in the same file. Rule of thumb (for example) -- a `main()` in a somewhat complex program won't do much more than calling several functions of your own modules.

Comment: 4.) (more technically) -- `system()` is *almost always* a bad idea. Its only valid use is when you're writing some frontend intended to execute/control an existing tool. (But then, some `execv*`/`execl*` function after `fork`ing on POSIX or `CreateProcess` on win32 might be better suited.) For everything else, use library functions to do the job without calling an external program.

Answer (score 2):

Your `fgets` does not wait for input in the full program because it sees a newline character (`'\n'`) in the `stdin` (left over by the previous `scanf`) and happily consumes it.

The solution is to clear the `stdin` (standard input stream) by using some method like:

```
int c; /* At the start of main */

while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF); /* Consume all characters until \n or EOF */
```

just before the problematic `fgets`.